# is there a shortcut to re-type the original filename and then edit it, when at the dired copy (C) minibuffer prompt

Tags: dired, default

While in a dired buffer, after pressing `C` to copy a file, often the new filename you want  is actually a variation of the original file name. Is there a easy way to get original file name in to the minibuffer prompt?

Comment: @NickD: This (the answer at least) is really not specific to Dired. It might be good to change this question to a general one, about inserting the default value into the minibuffer. And maybe change it to a Community question (?).

Comment: @Drew: I can probably generalize the answer to make it clear that this is not just for dired and maybe then generalize the question, but it is going to take some time (which I don't have atm). So I bookmarked the question and I'll try to get back to it asap: no promises though.

Comment: @NickD: Great. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The [dired section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html#Dired-Enter) of the Emacs manual says:

> The usual history and completion commands can be used in the
> minibuffer; in particular, ‘M-n’ puts the name of the visited file (if
> any) in the minibuffer (*note Minibuffer History::).

So, typing `M-n` at the minibuffer prompt will fill out the name and allow you to change it.